# supremum inequality

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

I want to show that

where the $\mathrm{ess }\inf$ of a measurable real function $f$ is defined as $\sup\{k\in \mathbb{R}:\mu (\mid f\mid<k)=0\}$ and $\mathrm{ess }\sup (f)=\inf\{k\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\mid f \mid >k)=0\}$ on a given measure space $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$.
Then $\mathrm{ess }\inf (f)$ is the supremum of those $k>0$ such that $\mid f\mid\geq k$ almost everywhere (w.r.t. $\mu$).  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388932/can-an-essential-supreme-infimum-norm-be-defined-in-terms-of-supreume-and-infimu) I found equivalent definitions. Using these definitions I concluded that
$$\mathrm{ess }\sup(f)=\inf\{\sup(f(A)):A\in \mathcal{A} ,\mu(A^c)=0\}\subseteq \{\sup(f(A)):A\in \mathcal{A}\}$$
which implies
$$\sup(\mathrm{ess }\sup(f))=\mathrm{ess }\sup(f)\leq \sup\{\sup(f(A)):A\in \mathcal{A}\}=\sup f(E)$$
since $\mathrm{ess }\sup(f)$ is singleton. Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand nothing of the last two lines of inequlities. Anyway it is true that the esssup is always smaller than the supremum (because it basically ignores some of the values).

Comment: @Yanko I understand this, intuitively. But can you give directions on how to show this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't understand your proof. I can give a proof of my own.

We want to show that the $\text{esssup}(f):= \inf\{k\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(|f|>k)=0\}$ is always smaller than the actual supremum.

To show this let $\sup(f)=M$. This means that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $f(x)\leq M$.

In particular this means that $\mu(|f|>M) = \mu(\emptyset)=0$. Therefore $M\in\{k\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(|f|>k)=0\}$ and so $M\geq \inf\{k\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(|f|>k)=0$. This proves the claim.

To show that $\text{esssup}(f) \geq \text{essinf}(f)$:

Let $\text{esssup}(f)=M$, $\text{essinf}(f)=N$. This means that $\mu(|f|>M)=0$ and $\mu(|f|<N)=0$.

If by contradiction $N>M$ then $$\mu(|f|<N+1) = \mu(|f|<N) + \mu(N\leq |f|<N+1)\leq 0+\mu(M<|f|)= 0$$ Therefore $N+1\in \{k\in\mathbb{R}:\mu(|f|<k)=0\}$ which contradicts the fact that $N$ is the supremum of this set.

Comment: Perfect. How would you argue that ess inf (f) is less equal ess sup (f)?  Can you give me a quick hint?

Comment: @Danmat I added that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! In the last equation, in the R.H.S of the equality, the term should be $\mu(N \leq \mid f\mid<N+1)$ right?

Comment: @Danmat you're correct.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that $\mu(N \leq \mid f\mid<N+1)\leq \mu(N<\mid f \mid)$? I only see that $\mu(N \leq \mid f\mid<N+1)\leq \mu(N\leq\mid f \mid)$

Comment: Although, the conclusion would be the same..

Comment: You're right, we can skip to $\mu(M<|f|)$. This is where we need the strict inequality (it is possible that the esssup equals to the essinf).